# What would a generic term be for a puck or ball in a sport?

Tags: hypernyms, sports

I'm a programmer and like to name my variables as accurately as possible (who knows who will be reading my code in a few years' time?)

I've been thinking about sports video games recently, and have thought about the idea of a generic sports game engine.  Most sports games have an arena, crowds, a playing surface and players.  They also have a puck, ball, discus, javelin, etc. and this has me wondering: What is a generic term for this object?  Something that could transcend all sports.

Edit: Since it seems there may be no *exact* term for this type of object, I'd gladly settle for some sort of analog.

Comment: Would the arrow in archery belong in this group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the "mark" - meaning a target?

Comment: This is a really good one too.

Comment: Usually the puck or ball is not the target.  The puck or ball is the projectile that is aimed at a target, such as a net or goal.

Comment: @oosterwal I was using mark as more of a generic term. Here is a contextual example, which I could have included originally - "keep your eye on the mark", and "target" meaning the target recepient object of some action, for example, hitting with a bat.

Comment: I agree with Rachel.  I wasn't talking about the goal/net, I was talking about the puck/ball/golden snitch.  The object that is neither player, nor implement, but the device which can score a goal/point/etc.

Answer (score 6):

Use "projectile."  This covers anything that is thrown, hit, shot, hurled, tossed, etc.

Comment: Actually, this isn't far off!  Congrats!

Answer (score 4):

There isn't one. Just use "ball" and have some comments.

Comment: True but disappointing.  Soviut, the English language has failed you!  ;)

Comment: I guess that's why I prefer programming languages then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since the item you are talking about is usually what two or more people fight for mastery over, what about something like *object of contention*?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. In Finnish we call any puck, ball or similar by the general term "peliväline" but there seems to be no English translation for this. I´m surprised!

Literal translation would be maybe "game device" or "sport apparatus"

I´m not sure either is helpful because they´re not really used.

Comment: Well, peliväline can be used for this, but it is not limited to just the "projectiles" - even the New Dictionary of Modern Finnish gives [the  example](http://www.kielitoimistonsanakirja.fi/netmot.exe?ListWord=peliv%C3%A4line&SearchWord=peliv%C3%A4line&page=results) ~"*Sticks/bats* and other *[game devices]*".